# PreSave Action validation for Yes/No Checkbox Column in a list new form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, newform

I have a requirement that if the yes/no check box column is checked then user dont need to fill the document name if it is not checked user should fill the document name so for that i using this presave action in the new form let me know what is wrong in this code i am not able to figure out.

```
function PreSaveAction() { 

var drpSection = $("select[title='Process']").val(); 
var drpDocumentName = $("select[title='Document Name']").val(); 
var drpDocumentNo = $("select[title='Document No']").val(); 
var drpRegional = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="Regional Document"]').val();

   if(drpSection == '0'){        
   alert("Please enter a Process"); 
   return false;  
    }
   else if(drpDocumentName == '0' && drpRegional == 'No'){        
   alert("Please enter a Document Name"); 
   return false;  
    }   
   else if(drpDocumentNo == '0'){ 
      alert("Please enter a Document No."); 
   return false;  
    }   
   else if(drpRegional == 'Yes' && drpDocumentName == '0'){
   return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if a checkbox field is checked in the list form, please use the Jquery below:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][title="testcheck"]').is(':checked')
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check what you are getting into,

```
var drpRegional = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="Regional Document"]').val();
```

because normally checkbox fields are boolean and they return True or false.

to find checked or not, you can use below example,

```
if($("#checkSurfaceEnvironment-1").prop('checked') == true){
//do something
}
```